# ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, processbuilder, 7zip

I´m studing about this subject in this page, but I can´t find the solution, how can I execute programs in cmd using ProcessBuilder? I want to compress, open, delete a file with 7zip using the command line. 
I have this code as example, but doesn´t work, cmd starts but doesn´t create the compress file:

```
String[] commands=
   {"cmd.exe", "7za", "a", "-t7z", "test.7z", "Test.txt", "/C", "start"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a little bit in Java (start() missing), a little bit in 7za (command line garbled)

```
new ProcessBuilder("7za", "a", "-t7z", "test.7z", "Test.txt").start();
```

This command works only if 7za is in your PATH...

If not you have to specify its path, under Windows:

```
new ProcessBuilder(
   "C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7za.exe", "a", "-t7z", "test.7z", "Test.txt").start();
```

Seven zip help:

```
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Usage: 7za <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]

<Commands>
  a: Add files to archive
  ...
<Switches>
  ...
  -t{Type}: Set type of archive
```

Comment: I got this: Cannot run program "7za": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Comment: You are under windows, the path may be C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe

Comment: On windows, only Cmd.exe need \, fopen() in C or ProcessBuilder in Java may use /