# How to fire command in Ubuntu Terminal using Java code

Tags: java, terminal, command

How to select a directory and fire a command via Terminal using java code in Ubuntu. 
For example i want to select the directory of tomcat like "cd /home/sree/tomcat/bin" and fire command like "sh shutdown.sh" and "sh startup.sh" for accessing sh files using java coding. 
Also need help for the above process in windows operating system. 
Please any one give me a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) to create a program that calls the desired commands you want (you would need to create a version for both Ubuntu and Windows). It offers a lot of flexibility and possibility to plugin to the system pipelines.

After that, you package your program as a jar and run it from the directory you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function:

```
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("a-command");
```

also, this post may help you:
http://blog.art-of-coding.eu/executing-operating-system-commands-from-java/

Answer (score 0):

There are two classes for this,

1. java.lang.Runtime
   More details

   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html
2. java.lang.ProcessBuilder 
   More details

   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

   [ProcessBuilder in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731699/processbuilder-in-java)

I have used process builder, for that you need to create an instance of ProcessBuilder first and call the start method on it, pass the command that you want to execute as constructor arguement.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls");
Process p = pb.start();
p.destroy();
```